# Imported font doesn't work

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've been trying for hours to use the Titillium Web custom font but haven't succeeded. Here's what I tried:

- Adding the following line in the `head` part of the overall template

  ```
  `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,400i,600,600i,700" rel="stylesheet">`
  ```
- Adding the following in `CSS`

  ```
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Titillium Web Bold';
      src: url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
           url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bold-webfont.svg") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Titillium Web BoldItalic';
      src: url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bolditalic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bolditalic-webfont.woff') format('woff');
           url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bolditalic-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-bolditalic-webfont.svg") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Titillium Web Italic';
      src: url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff');
           url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-italic-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-italic-webfont.svg") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Titillium Web Light';
      src: url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-light-webfont.woff') format('woff');
           url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-light-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-light-webfont.svg") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Titillium Web';
      src: url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
           url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-regular-webfont.svg") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Titillium Web Semibold';
      src: url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
           url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-semibold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("data/fonts/TWeb/titilliumweb-semibold-webfont.svg") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
  ```
- Using the font on an html element

  `a.random {font-family: 'Titillium Web';}` or `a.random {font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;}`

None worked.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to give an HTML element a `font` in your CSS. Right now, all you have done is declare a `font-face`

Comment: Hey. I did try to apply "font-family: 'Titillium Web'" on multiple html elements, but I had a random old font replacing the custom one instead, as if it wasn't working or exisitng.

Comment: You haven't shown it in the code you posted. Can you post that code?

Comment: My bad. Edited first post with some CSS I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Titillium+Web:300,400,400i,600,600i,700');
#f{
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
 #s{
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
 #t{
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="f">Sample</p>
<p id="s">Another Sample</p>
<p id="t">Last Sample</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code was working on Chrome only until I restarted Firefox. Now everything is purrfect. Thanks !